# Min and Max of the difference of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have two finite sets of numbers
$A,B$. Let $\min_A\equiv \min(A)$, $\max_A\equiv \max(A)$, $\min_B\equiv \min(B)$, $\max_B\equiv \max(B)$.

**(1)** Let $C$ be the set containing all possible differences between one element of $A$ and one element of $B$.

I want to compute $\min_C, \max_C$ from $\min_A, \max_A, \min_B, \max_B$

Is it correct that
$
\min_C=\min_A-\max_B$ and $
\max_C=\max_A-\min_B
$?

**(2)** Let $D$ be the set containing all possible sums between one element of $A$ and one element of $B$.

I want to compute $\min_D, \max_D$ from $\min_A, \max_A, \min_B, \max_B$

Is it correct that
$
\min_D=\min_A+\min_B$ and $
\max_D=\max_A+\max_B
$?

Comment: Are you assuming each starting min or max is (a) not $\pm \infty$ and (b) actualy attained and not merely a sup or inf?

Comment: (a) Is this necessary just to avoid cases like $\infty-\infty$? (b) Yes, I assume $A,B$ are finite sets.

Comment: yes then you are correct

Comment: Your result for (2) has a typo. It shoud be $\min_A+\min_B.$ [you had subscript $D$ on second min.]